# Why is the Microsoft Graph API using $ref in the URI?

Tags: rest, api, microsoft-graph-api, api-design

I have noticed that the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) is very often using `$ref` in the URIs.

For example [a member can be added to an Office 365 Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_members) using the following HTTP request:

```
POST /groups/{id}/members/$ref
```

Why is the `$ref` suffix used? Does this provide any value or advantage? Does  this have some special meaning in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft is implementing [OData](http://www.odata.org/). Section [4.4 Addressing References between Entities](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/cs01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-cs01-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc365046422) explains `$ref`:

> OData services are based on a data model that supports relationships as first class constructs. For example, an OData service could expose a collection of Products entities each of which are related to a Category entity.
>
> References between entities are addressable in OData just like entities themselves are (as described above) by appending a navigation property name followed by /$ref to the entity URL.